# Problem running arbitrage flashloan test app in JS

Tags: flash-loans, arbitrage

I´ve created a JS script to test arbitrage flashloan with Ethereum blockchain. When I attempt to run this code sample directly under the Truffle command line and run the **uniswapFactory.getPair(daiAddress, wethAddress)** line shown in below code extract:

```
require('dotenv').config();
const { INFURA_MAINNET_KEY, PRIVATE_KEY } = process.env;
const { ethers } = require('ethers');
const UniswapV2Pair = require(".././build/contracts/IUniswapV2Pair.json");
const UniswapV2Factory = require('.././build/contracts/IUniswapV2Factory.json');
const FACTORY_ABI = require(".././build/contracts/IUniswapV2Factory.json").abi;
const factoryAddress = "0x5C69bEe701ef814a2B6a3EDD4B1652CB9cc5aA6f";

const daiAddress = "0x6B175474E89094C44Da98b954EedeAC495271d0F";
const wethAddress = "0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2";

// use your own Infura node in production
const privateKey = process.env.PRIVATE_KEY;
const provider = new ethers.providers.InfuraProvider('mainnet', process.env.INFURA_MAINNET_KEY);
const wallet = new ethers.Wallet(privateKey, provider);
const factory = new ethers.Contract(factoryAddress, FACTORY_ABI, wallet);

const testBasic = async () => {
  const INTERVAL = 5000;      // ms

  const uniswapFactory = new ethers.Contract(
    factoryAddress,
    FACTORY_ABI, wallet
  );

  let uniswapDaiEth;
  uniswapDaiEth = new ethers.Contract(
    await uniswapFactory.getPair(daiAddress, wethAddress),
    FACTORY_ABI, wallet
  );
```

It spits out with following error shown below:

*Uncaught:
Error: missing revert data in call exception; Transaction reverted without a reason string [ See: https://links.ethers.org/v5-errors-CALL_EXCEPTION ] (data="0x", transaction={"from":"0x825c5e7d385F9f07e2312154B0Cf3CDd06396869","to":"0x5C69bEe701ef814a2B6a3EDD4B1652CB9cc5aA6f","data":"0xe6a439050000000000000000000000006b175474e89094c44da98b954eedeac495271d0f000000000000000000000000c02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2","accessList":null}, error={"reason":"bad response","code":"SERVER_ERROR","status":401,"headers":{"date":"Tue, 13 Sep 2022 13:05:36 GMT","content-type":"text/plain; charset=utf-8","content-length":"31","connection":"close","vary":"Accept-Encoding, Origin","www-authenticate":"Basic realm="Project ID is required in the URL"","x-content-type-options":"nosniff"},"body":"project id required in the url\n","requestBody":"{"method":"eth_call","params":[{"from":"0x825c5e7d385f9f07e2312154b0cf3cdd06396869","to":"0x5c69bee701ef814a2b6a3edd4b1652cb9cc5aa6f","data":"0xe6a439050000000000000000000000006b175474e89094c44da98b954eedeac495271d0f000000000000000000000000c02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2"},"latest"],"id":44,"jsonrpc":"2.0"}","requestMethod":"POST","url":"https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/6021b8788d0648c285535dc157a95e6f"}, code=CALL_EXCEPTION, version=providers/5.7.0)
at step (C:\Samuel\Blockchain\Flashloan-arbitrage-bot (uniswap v2)\node_modules@ethersproject\providers\lib\json-rpc-provider.js:48:23)
at InfuraProvider. (C:\Samuel\Blockchain\Flashloan-arbitrage-bot (uniswap v2)\node_modules@ethersproject\providers\src.ts\json-rpc-provider.ts:644:20)
at checkError (C:\Samuel\Blockchain\Flashloan-arbitrage-bot (uniswap v2)\node_modules@ethersproject\providers\src.ts\json-rpc-provider.ts:66:16)
at Logger.throwError (C:\Samuel\Blockchain\Flashloan-arbitrage-bot (uniswap v2)\node_modules@ethersproject\logger\src.ts\index.ts:281:20)
at Logger.makeError (C:\Samuel\Blockchain\Flashloan-arbitrage-bot (uniswap v2)\node_modules@ethersproject\logger\src.ts\index.ts:269:28) {
reason: 'missing revert data in call exception; Transaction reverted without a reason string',
code: 'CALL_EXCEPTION',
data: '0x',
transaction: {
from: '0x825c5e7d385F9f07e2312154B0Cf3CDd06396869',
to: '0x5C69bEe701ef814a2B6a3EDD4B1652CB9cc5aA6f',
data: '0xe6a439050000000000000000000000006b175474e89094c44da98b954eedeac495271d0f000000000000000000000000c02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2',
accessList: null
},
error: Error: bad response (status=401, headers={"date":"Tue, 13 Sep 2022 13:05:36 GMT","content-type":"text/plain; charset=utf-8","content-length":"31","connection":"close","vary":"Accept-Encoding, Origin","www-authenticate":"Basic realm="Project ID is required in the URL"","x-content-type-options":"nosniff"}, body="project id required in the url\n", requestBody="{"method":"eth_call","params":[{"from":"0x825c5e7d385f9f07e2312154b0cf3cdd06396869","to":"0x5c69bee701ef814a2b6a3edd4b1652cb9cc5aa6f","data":"0xe6a439050000000000000000000000006b175474e89094c44da98b954eedeac495271d0f000000000000000000000000c02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2"},"latest"],"id":44,"jsonrpc":"2.0"}", requestMethod="POST", url="https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/6021b8788d0648c285535dc157a95e6f", code=SERVER_ERROR, version=web/5.7.0)
at Logger.makeError (C:\Samuel\Blockchain\Flashloan-arbitrage-bot (uniswap v2)\node_modules@ethersproject\logger\src.ts\index.ts:269:28)
at Logger.throwError (C:\Samuel\Blockchain\Flashloan-arbitrage-bot (uniswap v2)\node_modules@ethersproject\logger\src.ts\index.ts:281:20)
at C:\Samuel\Blockchain\Flashloan-arbitrage-bot (uniswap v2)\node_modules@ethersproject\web\src.ts\index.ts:302:24
at step (C:\Samuel\Blockchain\Flashloan-arbitrage-bot (uniswap v2)\node_modules@ethersproject\web\lib\index.js:33:23)

at Object.next (C:\Samuel\Blockchain\Flashloan-arbitrage-bot (uniswap v2)\node_modules@ethersproject\web\lib\index.js:14:53)
at fulfilled (C:\Samuel\Blockchain\Flashloan-arbitrage-bot (uniswap v2)\node_modules@ethersproject\web\lib\index.js:5:58)

at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
reason: 'bad response',
code: 'SERVER_ERROR',
status: 401,
headers: {
date: 'Tue, 13 Sep 2022 13:05:36 GMT',
'content-type': 'text/plain; charset=utf-8',
'content-length': '31',
connection: 'close',
vary: 'Accept-Encoding, Origin',
**'www-authenticate': 'Basic realm="Project ID is required in the URL"',**
'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff'
},
body: 'project id required in the url\n',
requestBody: '{"method":"eth_call","params":[{"from":"0x825c5e7d385f9f07e2312154b0cf3cdd06396869","to":"0x5c69bee701ef814a2b6a3edd4b1652cb9cc5aa6f","data":"0xe6a439050000000000000000000000006b175474e89094c44da98b954eedeac495271d0f000000000000000000000000c02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2"},"latest"],"id":44,"jsonrpc":"2.0"}',
requestMethod: 'POST',
url: 'https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/6021b8788d0648c285535dc157a95e6f'
}
}*

The only useful error I can see that could give us a clue is where it says "Basic realm="Project ID is required in the URL". Does this mean I would have to add this into the Infura mainnet URL that I supplied?

Any help would be greatly appreciated as it´s driving me bonkers for a couple of days now.

Thanks in advance for your help,
Sam

---

Yes am trying to perform the following steps:
a) Use flash swaps to optimistically borrow an asset from the lower priced pool
b) Immediately sell the asset in the higher-priced pool
c) Repay back the flash swap loan and pocket the difference.

From below code snippet, it´s a flashloan since the last data parameter is not empty which actually triggers the flashloan in the outset.

IUniswapV2Pair(pairAddress).swap(
amount0,
amount1,
address(this),
bytes('not empty')
);

One other question, and I apologise if it´s stupid question, but why would I need to connect a wallet to a UniswapV2Factory in order to retrieve the existence of token pair i.e. DAI/WETH in my attempted case? It sends out another error. Any insights please?

Thank you very much much!

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot use uniswap factory and uniswap router on ganache.

I suggest to use it on a tesnet like goerli as for now others testnets are no longer maintained.

If you can provide more information, it would be helpfull to find the culprit.

Comment: I´ve forked the mainnet into local Ganache environment where I´ve deployed the app into and now it seems it´s progressing but popping out the following error message:           
        reason: 'UniswapV2: INSUFFICIENT_LIQUIDITY'.                                                                                                I understood that the liquidity concept is only applicable for non-flash swap contracts/transactions, is that correct?
It seems very odd getting this error message. Looking forward to your reply. Thank you!

Comment: My second question is, are you making a triangular arbitrage ? Or an ordinary arbitrage ? Because i don't see the router of Uniswap ? As i see you are trying to do a flash swap and not a flash loan.. am i wrong ? Also, the **amount0** in StartArbitrage is 5000000 which might be in **Wei**.